# Product price matrix

Tags: magento-1.7, price, configurable-product

I'm planing to use Magento to sell products with multiple options ( 3-5 ). Each of them changes final price. There is no fixed / percentage connection, so I have to create matrix of prices
Whats the proper way of implementing?

I found this module:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-matrix.html, but reviews are bad and its limited to 2 dimensions.

I was thinking about using configurable products based on 4-5 attributes.

Does anybody knows solution / extension that will work for me?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of that particular developer, their service level has improved a lot over the last couple of years.

If you don't need to track inventory, then you could just use custom options which would be a great deal more simple.

You could also consider using better configurable products (http://www.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html) which simplifies the method of structuring your prices.

It would be good to know more about your specific requirements though; how many products are you talking about, how many options would you have for each attribute, etc.

Comment: I don't need stack control, so it makes things easier. I'm going to have around 10 types of products, each of them will have different attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need and I am using this extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/price-matrix-extension.html

David

Comment: If you have used the extension previously, kindly also share benefits it provided in terms of features against the requirements in the question.